# How can a code identify if it is being called by windows application or web application

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows

I am developing a .net component. Is there any foolproof way of identifying whether a web application or a windows application is calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for

```
HttpContext.Current
```

which gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request.